# Program in 8086 assembly language : program that finds all bigger numbers than a single input number from an input array of numbers

Tags: assembly, x86-16

I dont know if i am clear but i need a program that will take numbers(#1) that i input, a single input number(#2) and it needs to find all numbers bigger than number #2 from the array of numbers given.

```
.model small
.stack 100
.data
sir db 80 dup('$')
m1 db 'Introduceti sirul:$'
m2 db 13,10,'Introduceti un caracter:$'
m2 db 13,10,'Cel mai mare caracter este: $'
max db 0,'$'
.code
mov ax,@data
mov ds,ax
mov ah,9h
mov dx,offset m1
int 21h

mov bx,0
mov cx,80
mov ah,3fh
mov dx,offset sir
int 21h

mov ah,9h
mov dx,offset m2
int 21h

mov ah,1
int 21h

mov si,offset sir
mov ah,[si]
next: mov al,[si]
cmp al,13 
jz sfarsit
cmp al,ah 
jle nu
mov ah,al
nu: inc si
jmp next

sfarsit:
mov bl,ah 
mov ah,9
mov dx,offset m2
int 21h

mov dl,bl
mov ah,2
int 21h

mov ah,4ch
int 21h
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Currently your program just finds the biggest number aka ASCII (character code) in the inputted array at *sir*. You don't use the separate input at all! Start by storing this input:

```
    mov     ah, 01h    ; DOS.InputCharacter
    int     21h
    mov     char, al
```

Then look in the array to find anything that is bigger. Every item that is bigger gets displayed immediately.

```
    mov     si, offset sir
next:
    mov     dl, [si]
    cmp     dl, 13 
    je      sfarsit
    cmp     dl, char
    jbe     nu         ; Ignore if not bigger

    mov     ah, 02h    ; DOS.DisplayCharacter
    int     21h

nu:
    inc     si
    jmp     next
sfarsit:
```

Please notice that the array elements are in effect **characters** and that you should treat these as unsigned quantities. Therefore don't use `jle` which is for signed comparisons, but rather use `jbe` which is for unsigned comparisons.

You will have to re-think when to output the 3rd message.

Did you see that your 2nd and 3rd messages are both labeled *m2*? The assembler will reject this.

Comment: so i did what you say and when it needs to show all nubers that are bigger than the one i input just shows like a smiley face?

Comment: m1 translates to "Input an array" , m2 "Input a number", and m3(the second m2) "The bigger numbers are".

Comment: @Alex Your *array* is really a **string of characters**, your *single number* is really a **character**, and your *list of bigger numbers* is really a (somewhat shorter) **string of characters**. That's how you defined the input and that's what your (and my) code produces.